# Why does my colorscheme look different when I run Vim with sudo?

Tags: colorscheme

I installed colorscheme "jellybeans" for Vim. Why does the colors look differently when I run Vim with and without sudo?

Example on the screen below - the left one is without sudo, the right is with sudo. The one with sudo is working properly - how can I make Vim to have the same colors without using sudo?

[image]

I use

```
Linux Mint 17.2 (x64)  
gnome-terminal 3.6.2  
bash 4.3.11  
tmux 1.8  
Vim 7.4
```

The value of my `$TERM` variable is:

```
$TERM=screen-256color
```

And the result is the same with `sudo $SHELL -c 'echo $TERM'`

Here is my [vimrc file](https://github.com/tkossak/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc).

### EDIT - SOLUTION:

Colorscheme file was lacking read permission for "others". Fixed with:
`sudo chmod +r /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/jellybeans.vim`

Comment: `sudo echo $TERM` will always print the same value as `echo $TERM` - the variable is expanded before `sudo` comes into play. What does `sudo $SHELL -c 'echo $TERM'` say? How did you install the colour scene? And you should use `sudoedit` instead of `sudo vim`.

Comment: maybe as a sudo its not loading the right vimrc? Try "source <pathtoyourvimrc>".

Comment: @muru `sudo $SHELL -c 'echo $TERM'` gives me the same value of "screen-256color". I installed the colorscheme by copying `jellybeans.vim` file into the folder `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors`. Thank you for `sudoedit` tip.

Comment: @philolo1 i think `sudo vim` loads my local .vimrc because i deleted root's .vimrc and all my plugins/keys work as the should. I tried `source /home/kossak/.vimrc` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to your answer. Mark your answer as accepted. There might be a timeout, but you can accept your own answers.

Comment: Try installing neovim instead of regular vim. It's a tidier vim with some useful features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was: making sure users who run vim can actually read the colorscheme file. Giving everyone read permission is done with:

```
sudo chmod +r /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/jellybeans.vim
```

Answer (score 10):

When you run vim with sudo, you are running as user root, so you are using root's vimrc and .vim. Your colorscheme and other customizations set in your ~/.vimrc are not being used. You can see this by executing

```
:scriptnames
```

Comment: I don't hink only root .vimrc file is used when running `sudo vim`. Just now i deleted root's .vimrc file and my keys/plugins defined in my user's .vimrc still work when running `sudo vim`. (when i log as root first and then run vim, they don't work). When i run `scriptnames` i see `jeelybeans.vim` only with `sudo vim` not with `vim`.

Comment: this `:scriptnames` led me to solution - `jellybeans.vim` file was lacking read permission for "others". Modify your answer so i can mark it as solution. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think my answer was the solution. In fact, after reading your solution and re-reading your question, I see that I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of running `sudo vim` to run `vim` as root, run `sudoedit filename`.

This creates a temporary copy of the file, edits that copy without root privileges, and copies the changes to the original file. You may need to set `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` to `vim` (e.g. `export VISUAL=vim`) to get `sudoedit` to use the correct editor. This is safer and uses your Vim configuration instead of root’s.

If you want to use `gvim` instead, you’ll need to use the `--nofork` option: `export VISUAL='gvim --nofork'`.

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of sudoedit before.